# Does using `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` dismiss the current ViewController or just return to the previous?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I was wondering if `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` actually dismisses the View Controller it is being called on or if it just returns to the previous? If so, does this mean that I must manually dismiss the View Controller along with using the above code? Thanks.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. "pop" is "pop" (a pushed view controller). "dismiss" is "dismiss" (a presented view controller). You seem to be mixing apples with oranges. And there is no sense here of what the situation actually is and what you are actually trying to do; you should probably pose your question in terms of specifics, not generalities. I'll try to answer but I'm just guessing what you mean. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pop a view controller off a UINavigationController's navigation stack, the UINavigationController *releases* the popped view controller and by default it goes out of existence. You can see this by implementing that view controller's `deinit`.

If you *don't* see `deinit` called, then that view controller is leaking because you have a retain cycle, and you need to worry about why that is.